How to open multiple links on a page at once in new tabs or window from chrome's dev tool console?
Assume a website containing links:
<a href="https://www.google.com">google</a>
<a href="https://www.yahoo.com">yahoo</a>
<a href="https://www.bing.com">bing</a>

I want to open each one of them in a new tab from chrome's dev tool console.
I though I could achieve this via running the following from the console:
const as = document.querySelectorAll('a');
as.forEach(a => a.setAttribute('target', '_blank'));
as.forEach(a => a.click())

Yet it only opens the first one, then stops.
I also tried window.open:
[...document.querySelectorAll('a')].map(a => a.href).forEach(window.open)

or
[...document.querySelectorAll('a')].map(a => a.href).forEach(href => window.open(href, '_blank'));

This too only opens the first link, not the others.
How do I open all links in a new tab or window from chrome's dev console?

Actually, nix that last comment. I just remembered that modern browsers will not open multiple windows via automation to prevent runaway popups. New windows can be opened as a result of the user explicitly performing an action that causes it, for example by clicking on a button.

From MDN "Modern browsers have strict popup blocker policies. Popup windows must be opened in direct response to user input, and a separate user gesture event is required for each window.open() call. This prevents sites from spamming users with lots of windows. However, this poses an issue for multi-window applications. You can design your applications to:
Open no more than 1 new window at once.
Reuse existing windows to display different pages.
Advise users on how to update their browser settings to allow multiple windows."

It's a little surprising that this is enforced in the console, isn't it? There's little need for popup blocking there.

You need to explicitly give permissions for every site you want to open multiple files

That would have to be done by the visitor and as a result cannot be relied upon as having been done by the developer.

@ScottMarcus My use case only exists within the realm of my local machine so this solves my issue.

@ScottMarcus I think my answer solves your issue so please mark the answer as right

It's not my question, so I can't mark as correct.

@ScottMarcus sorry, you are right
